# Adding totals in javascript, syntax error

Tags: javascript, html, syntax-error

Im building an exercise game based off of Dragon Ball Z for fun. This page is where you type in all your numbers and record your progress.

Live at: http://surrealmayhem.com/dbzgame/record_progress.html

Now, Ive got 99% of this page working so far. What Im trying to accomplish is to take the value from everything in the right-hand "TOTALS" column and have it add up in the long progress bar at the bottom of the page.

Each individual progress bar in the TOTALS column works. But for some reason I cant figure out the progress bar at the bottom wont work. Im still a beginner so I suspect its syntax.

I will post my entire code since I must be screwing something up somewhere.

```
<script>
function balanceexp(){
    var arr = document.getElementsByName('balexp');
    var tot=0;
    for(var z=0;z<arr.length;z++){
        if(parseInt(arr[z].value))
            tot += parseInt(arr[z].value);
    }
    document.getElementById('balancetotal').value = tot;
}
</script>

<script>
function powerexp(){
    var arr = document.getElementsByName('powexp');
    var tot=0;
    for(var y=0;y<arr.length;y++){
        if(parseInt(arr[y].value))
            tot += parseInt(arr[y].value);
    }
    document.getElementById('powertotal').value = tot;
}
</script>
>

<script>
function staminaexp(){
    var arr = document.getElementsByName('staexp');
    var tot=0;
    for(var w=0;w<arr.length;w++){
        if(parseInt(arr[w].value))
            tot += parseInt(arr[w].value);
    }
    document.getElementById('staminatotal').value = tot;
}
</script>

<script>
function agilityexp(){
    var arr = document.getElementsByName('aglexp');
    var tot=0;
    for(var o=0;o<arr.length;o++){
        if(parseInt(arr[o].value))
            tot += parseInt(arr[o].value);
    }
    document.getElementById('agilitytotal').value = tot;
}
</script>

<script>
function controlexp(){
    var arr = document.getElementsByName('conexp');
    var tot=0;
    for(var s=0;s<arr.length;s++){
        if(parseInt(arr[s].value))
            tot += parseInt(arr[s].value);
    }
    document.getElementById('controltotal').value = tot;
}
</script>




<script type="text/javascript">

function findTotal() {
  var names = ['balancetotal', 'powertotal', 'staminatotal', 'agilitytotal', 'controltotal'];
  var total = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
    var value = document.getElementById(names[i]).value,
        x = parseInt(value, 10) || 0;
    total += x;
  }
  document.getElementById('exp_total').value = total;
}


</script>


</head>

<body>


<div class="wrapper">

<div class="column"></div>

<div class="start">


<center><font size="5">"My Progress" -  <a href="index.html">Home</a></font></center><br /><br />


This is a sacred place. This is where you will come at the beginning and end of every day to track and record your progress. In other words, this is exactly where your story is being written.   <br /><br />

<div class="left">



<img src="pics/goku_badge.png" title="Goku Badge: Completed 10,000 reps in one day">
<img src="pics/piccolodevilbadge.png" title="Piccolo Devil Badge: Defeated Piccolo in battle.">  
<img src="pics/100repsall_badge.png" title="100 Reps Badge: Completed 100 repititions of each exercise."> 
<img src="pics/100punches_badge.png" title="100 Punches Badge: Completed 100 punches.">  
<img src="pics/1star_dragonball.png" title="You found the One Star Dragon Ball!">  

</div>
<div class="right">

<table border="0px" cellpadding="5px">
<tr><td colspan="4" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
<center><b>TOTALS:</b></center>
</td></tr><tr><td colspan="4"></td></tr>

<tr>
<td bgcolor="#BBBBDD">BALANCE:</td>
<td bgcolor="#BBBBDD"><progress min="0" max="200000" value="balancetotal" id="balancetotal" style="width:190px;"></progress>
</td></tr>
<tr>
<td><input onblur="balanceexp()" type="text" name="balexp" id="qty" style="width:30px;" onchange="findTotal()" > Leg Lifts</td>
<td><input onblur="balanceexp()" type="text" name="balexp" id="qty" style="width:30px;" onchange="findTotal()" > Crunches</td></tr>
<td><input onblur="balanceexp()" type="text" name="balexp" id="qty" style="width:30px;" onchange="findTotal()" > Rows</td>
<td><input onblur="balanceexp()" type="text" name="balexp" id="qty" style="width:30px;" onchange="findTotal()" > Lowerback extensions</td></tr>
</tr>


<tr>
<td bgcolor="#CCDDCC">POWER:</td>
<td bgcolor="#CCDDCC"><progress min="0" max="200000" value="powertotal" id="powertotal" style="width:190px;"></progress>
</td></tr>
<tr>
<td><input onblur="powerexp()" type="text" name="powexp" id="qty" style="width:30px;" onchange="findTotal()" > Push ups</td>
<td><input onblur="powerexp()" type="text" name="powexp" id="qty" style="width:30px;" onchange="findTotal()" > Sit ups</td></tr>
<td><input onblur="powerexp()" type="text" name="powexp" id="qty" style="width:30px;" onchange="findTotal()" > Pull ups</td>
<td><input onblur="powerexp()" type="text" name="powexp" id="qty" style="width:30px;" onchange="findTotal()" > Chin ups</td></tr>
<td><input onblur="powerexp()" type="text" name="powexp" id="qty" style="width:30px;" onchange="findTotal()" > Dips</td>
<td><input onblur="powerexp()" type="text" name="powexp" id="qty" style="width:30px;" onchange="findTotal()" > Squats</td></tr>
<td><input onblur="powerexp()" type="text" name="powexp" id="qty" style="width:30px;" onchange="findTotal()" > Flies</td>
<td><input onblur="powerexp()" type="text" name="powexp" id="qty" style="width:30px;" onchange="findTotal()" > Presses</td></tr>
<td><input onblur="powerexp()" type="text" name="powexp" id="qty" style="width:30px;" onchange="findTotal()" > Lifts</td>
<td><input onblur="powerexp()" type="text" name="powexp" id="qty" style="width:30px;" onchange="findTotal()" > Curls</td></tr>


<tr>
<td bgcolor="#DDDDAA">CONTROL:</td>
<td bgcolor="#DDDDAA"><progress min="0" max="200000" value=" controltotal" id="controltotal" style="width:190px;"></progress>
</td></tr>
<tr>
<td><input onblur="controlexp()" type="text" name="conexp" id="qty" style="width:30px;" onchange="findTotal()" > Punches</td>
<td><input onblur="controlexp()" type="text" name="conexp" id="qty" style="width:30px;" onchange="findTotal()" > Vacuums</td></tr>
<td><input onblur="controlexp()" type="text" name="conexp" id="qty" style="width:30px;" onchange="findTotal()" > Kicks</td>
<td><input onblur="controlexp()" type="text" name="conexp" id="qty" style="width:30px;" onchange="findTotal()" > Forearms work</td></tr>


<tr>
<td bgcolor="#CCA9A9">STAMINA:</td>
<td bgcolor="#CCA9A9"><progress min="0" max="200000" value=" staminatotal" id="staminatotal" style="width:190px;"></progress>
</td></tr>
<tr>
<td><input onblur="staminaexp()" type="text" name="staexp" id="qty" style="width:30px;;" onchange="findTotal()" > Planks</td>
<td><input onblur="staminaexp()" type="text" name="staexp" id="qty" style="width:30px;;" onchange="findTotal()" > Burpees</td></tr>
<td><input onblur="staminaexp()" type="text" name="staexp" id="qty" style="width:30px;;" onchange="findTotal()" > Hangs</td>
<td><input onblur="staminaexp()" type="text" name="staexp" id="qty" style="width:30px;;" onchange="findTotal()" > Wall sits</td></tr>


<tr>
<td bgcolor="#AACCDD">AGILITY:</td>
<td bgcolor="#AACCDD"><progress min="0" max="200000" value="agilitytotal" id="agilitytotal" style="width:190px;"></progress>
</td></tr>
<tr>
<td><input onblur="agilityexp()" type="text" name="aglexp" id="qty" style="width:30px;" onchange="findTotal()" > Walk / Run</td>
<td><input onblur="agilityexp()" type="text" name="aglexp" id="qty" style="width:30px;" onchange="findTotal()" > Jumping Jacks</td></tr>
<td><input onblur="agilityexp()" type="text" name="aglexp" id="qty" style="width:30px;" onchange="findTotal()" > Lunges</td>
<td><input onblur="agilityexp()" type="text" name="aglexp" id="qty" style="width:30px;" onchange="findTotal()" > Box Jumps</td></tr>

</table>

<br />
<input type="button" value="Print" name="printbutton" onclick="window.print();">


</div> 

<center>
Total experience: <br /> <!-- <input type="text" name="total" id="total"/> / 1,000,000 pts -->
<progress min="0" max="1000000" value="exp_total" id="exp_total" style="width:800px;"></progress>
</center>


</div>
</center>

</div>




<div class="column"></div>
```

I also have a previous script I wrote that takes numbers and totals them that actually works, and I tried to adapt that to a progress bar, but that didnt work either. Ill post it here, I thought it might be a simpler solution. I dont really understand loops yet and I like this script better, but I dont know how to adapt it to a progress bar. I dont know if its of any use but I thought Id post both.

```
<script>
function findTotal(){
var bal_t = parseInt(document.getElementById("balancetotal").value);
var pow_t = parseInt(document.getElementById("poweretotal").value);
var con_t = parseInt(document.getElementById("controltotal").value);
var agl_t = parseInt(document.getElementById("agilitytotal").value);
var sta_t = parseInt(document.getElementById("staminatotal").value);

var total_exp = document.getElementById("total");
total_exp.value = bal_t + pow_t + con_t + agl_t + sta_t;

</script>
```

Comment: on page you have js error:  var arr = document.getElementsById('qty');
should be getElementById

Comment: dont resuse `ids`, thats what classes are for.

Comment: TypeError: document.getElementsById is not a function..its element not elements

Comment: yea I just edited my question to include I also tried that, and updated the page. I was still working on it offline. My bad.

Comment: @A.B I totally missed that spelling error. Thanks. Ill get my original code witht he function back up, I wasnt sure how to call it so I took it out. It wasnt working before either.

Comment: Please see my answer below. Does that fix the problem?

Comment: @Michael Laszio I edited my code to accommodate both answers I got and neither made it work. I tried both separately and together, neither way worked.

Comment: I see the problem and I've revised my answer. Please edit your code as I advise below and test it again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One problem is that `allexp.length` evaluates to `undefined` in this line:

```
for (var i = 0; i < allexp.length; i++) {
```

You're assuming that `length` is an attribute of `allexp`, as though it were an array. However, you defined `allexp` as an addition or concatenation:

```
var allexp = (balancetotal + powertotal + staminatotal + agilitytotal + controltotal);
```

To make an array of strings, do this instead:

```
var names = ['balancetotal', 'powertotal', 'staminatotal', 'agilitytotal', 'controltotal'];
```

Another problem is that you're treating the strings as though they had `value` attributes. Each string is actually the ID of an HTML element. Therefore, you should look up the element using `getElementById` and then get its value.

```
for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
  var value = document.getElementById(names[i]).value,  // Get value from element.
      x = parseInt(value, 10) || 0;  // Parse in base 10. Default to 0.
  tot += x;
}
```

A final problem is that you aren't calling `findTotal()` anywhere. When do you want it to run? If you want it to run after the balance total has been updated, for example, you should insert a call to `findTotal()` as the last line of the `balanceexp()` function definition.

To summarize, replace the current `findTotal()` function with this:

```
function findTotal() {
  var names = ['balancetotal', 'powertotal', 'staminatotal', 'agilitytotal', 'controltotal'];
  var total = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
    var value = document.getElementById(names[i]).value,
        x = parseInt(value, 10) || 0;
    total += x;
  }
  document.getElementById('total').value = total;
}
```

And then make sure you call `findTotal()` when you want it to run.

Below is a live demonstration incorporating the changes I have described. To try it out, click on the "Run code snippet" button and then on the "Full page" button that shows up inside the box.

```js
function findTotal() {
  var names = ['balancetotal', 'powertotal', 'staminatotal', 'agilitytotal', 'controltotal'];
  var total = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
    var value = document.getElementById(names[i]).value,
        x = parseInt(value, 10) || 0;
    total += x;
  }
  document.getElementById('total').value = total;
}

function balanceexp(){
    var arr = document.getElementsByName('balexp');
    var tot=0;
    for(var z=0;z<arr.length;z++){
        if(parseInt(arr[z].value))
            tot += parseInt(arr[z].value);
    }
    document.getElementById('balancetotal').value = tot;
    findTotal();
}

function powerexp(){
    var arr = document.getElementsByName('powexp');
    var tot=0;
    for(var y=0;y<arr.length;y++){
        if(parseInt(arr[y].value))
            tot += parseInt(arr[y].value);
    }
    document.getElementById('powertotal').value = tot;
    findTotal();
}

function staminaexp(){
    var arr = document.getElementsByName('staexp');
    var tot=0;
    for(var w=0;w<arr.length;w++){
        if(parseInt(arr[w].value))
            tot += parseInt(arr[w].value);
    }
    document.getElementById('staminatotal').value = tot;
    findTotal();
}

function agilityexp(){
    var arr = document.getElementsByName('aglexp');
    var tot=0;
    for(var o=0;o<arr.length;o++){
        if(parseInt(arr[o].value))
            tot += parseInt(arr[o].value);
    }
    document.getElementById('agilitytotal').value = tot;
    findTotal();
}

function controlexp(){
    var arr = document.getElementsByName('conexp');
    var tot=0;
    for(var s=0;s<arr.length;s++){
        if(parseInt(arr[s].value))
            tot += parseInt(arr[s].value);
    }
    document.getElementById('controltotal').value = tot;
    findTotal();
}
```

```css
body{
background-color: orange;
margin: 0px;}

.wrapper{
height: auto;
width: 1260px;
margin: auto;
background-color: transparent;}

.start{
height: 800px;
width: 800px;
background-color: white;
margin: 35px 20px 10px 20px;
padding: 25px;
border: solid 10px #000000;
clear: none;
float: left;}

.left{
height: 610px;
width: 348px;
background-color: transparent;
clear: none;
float: left;
margin-right: 20px;
border: solid 1px #cccccc;
padding: 20px;
overflow-y: scroll;
overflow-x: hidden;}


.right{
height: 610px;
width: 348px;
background-color: transparent;
clear: none;
float: left;
margin-bottom: 8px;
border: solid 1px #cccccc;
padding: 20px;
overflow-y: scroll;
overflow-x: hidden;}

.column{
height: 1000px;
width: 165px;
background-image: url(pics/column.png);
background-color: transparent;
clear: none;
float: left;
overflow: hidden;}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">

<div class="column"></div>

<div class="start">

    
<center><font size="5">"My Progress" -  <a href="index.html">Home</a></font></center><br /><br />


This is a sacred place. This is where you will come at the beginning and end of every day to track and record your progress. In other words, this is exactly where your story is being written.   <br /><br />

<div class="left">



<img src="pics/goku_badge.png" title="Goku Badge: Completed 10,000 reps in one day">
<img src="pics/piccolodevilbadge.png" title="Piccolo Devil Badge: Defeated Piccolo in battle.">  
<img src="pics/100repsall_badge.png" title="100 Reps Badge: Completed 100 repititions of each exercise."> 
<img src="pics/100punches_badge.png" title="100 Punches Badge: Completed 100 punches.">  
<img src="pics/1star_dragonball.png" title="You found the One Star Dragon Ball!">  

</div>
<div class="right">

<table border="0px" cellpadding="5px">
<tr><td colspan="4" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
<center><b>TOTALS:</b></center>
</td></tr><tr><td colspan="4"></td></tr>

<tr>
<td bgcolor="#BBBBDD">BALANCE:</td>
<td bgcolor="#BBBBDD"><progress min="0" max="200000" value="balancetotal" id="balancetotal" style="width:190px;"></progress>
</td></tr>
<tr>
<td><input onblur="balanceexp()" type="text" name="balexp" id="qty" style="width:30px;"> Leg Lifts</td>
<td><input onblur="balanceexp()" type="text" name="balexp" id="qty" style="width:30px;"> Crunches</td></tr>
<td><input onblur="balanceexp()" type="text" name="balexp" id="qty" style="width:30px;"> Rows</td>
<td><input onblur="balanceexp()" type="text" name="balexp" id="qty" style="width:30px;"> Lowerback extensions</td></tr>
</tr>


<tr>
<td bgcolor="#CCDDCC">POWER:</td>
<td bgcolor="#CCDDCC"><progress min="0" max="200000" value="powertotal" id="powertotal" style="width:190px;"></progress>
</td></tr>
<tr>
<td><input onblur="powerexp()" type="text" name="powexp" id="qty" style="width:30px;"> Push ups</td>
<td><input onblur="powerexp()" type="text" name="powexp" id="qty" style="width:30px;"> Sit ups</td></tr>
<td><input onblur="powerexp()" type="text" name="powexp" id="qty" style="width:30px;"> Pull ups</td>
<td><input onblur="powerexp()" type="text" name="powexp" id="qty" style="width:30px;"> Chin ups</td></tr>
<td><input onblur="powerexp()" type="text" name="powexp" id="qty" style="width:30px;"> Dips</td>
<td><input onblur="powerexp()" type="text" name="powexp" id="qty" style="width:30px;"> Squats</td></tr>
<td><input onblur="powerexp()" type="text" name="powexp" id="qty" style="width:30px;"> Flies</td>
<td><input onblur="powerexp()" type="text" name="powexp" id="qty" style="width:30px;"> Presses</td></tr>
<td><input onblur="powerexp()" type="text" name="powexp" id="qty" style="width:30px;"> Lifts</td>
<td><input onblur="powerexp()" type="text" name="powexp" id="qty" style="width:30px;"> Curls</td></tr>


<tr>
<td bgcolor="#DDDDAA">CONTROL:</td>
<td bgcolor="#DDDDAA"><progress min="0" max="200000" value=" controltotal" id="controltotal" style="width:190px;"></progress>
</td></tr>
<tr>
<td><input onblur="controlexp()" type="text" name="conexp" id="qty" style="width:30px;"> Punches</td>
<td><input onblur="controlexp()" type="text" name="conexp" id="qty" style="width:30px;"> Vacuums</td></tr>
<td><input onblur="controlexp()" type="text" name="conexp" id="qty" style="width:30px;"> Kicks</td>
<td><input onblur="controlexp()" type="text" name="conexp" id="qty" style="width:30px;"> Forearm squeeze</td></tr>


<tr>
<td bgcolor="#CCA9A9">STAMINA:</td>
<td bgcolor="#CCA9A9"><progress min="0" max="200000" value=" staminatotal" id="staminatotal" style="width:190px;"></progress>
</td></tr>
<tr>
<td><input onblur="staminaexp()" type="text" name="staexp" id="qty" style="width:30px;;"> Planks</td>
<td><input onblur="staminaexp()" type="text" name="staexp" id="qty" style="width:30px;;"> Burpees</td></tr>
<td><input onblur="staminaexp()" type="text" name="staexp" id="qty" style="width:30px;;"> Hangs</td>
<td><input onblur="staminaexp()" type="text" name="staexp" id="qty" style="width:30px;;"> Wall sits</td></tr>


<tr>
<td bgcolor="#AACCDD">AGILITY:</td>
<td bgcolor="#AACCDD"><progress min="0" max="200000" value="agilitytotal" id="agilitytotal" style="width:190px;"></progress>
</td></tr>
<tr>
<td><input onblur="agilityexp()" type="text" name="aglexp" id="qty" style="width:30px;"> Walk / Run</td>
<td><input onblur="agilityexp()" type="text" name="aglexp" id="qty" style="width:30px;"> Jumping Jacks</td></tr>
<td><input onblur="agilityexp()" type="text" name="aglexp" id="qty" style="width:30px;"> Lunges</td>
<td><input onblur="agilityexp()" type="text" name="aglexp" id="qty" style="width:30px;"> Box Jumps</td></tr>

</table>

<br />
<input type="button" value="Print" name="printbutton" onclick="window.print();">


</div> 

<center>
Total experience: <br /> <!-- <input type="text" name="total" id="total"/> / 1,000,000 pts -->
<progress min="0" max="1000000" value="total" id="total" style="width:800px;"></progress>
</center>
    

</div>
</center>

</div>




<div class="column"></div>
```

Comment: I revised my code but its still not working. I feel like Im missing something simple. Could you post all the code in a single snippet? Its hard for me to follow when its cut up, Im probably putting something in the wrong spot.

Comment: I've edited my answer to show the entire `findTotal()` function definition. In addition, I've explained that you have to call `findTotal()` when you want it to run.

Comment: Ive got it set for body onload="findTotal()" , which is what I want, I dont want someone to have to manually type in a 0 in every box before itll work.  and I copied & pasted your code into mine, but its still not working.

Comment: So you're calling `findTotal()` just once, at page load, when all the inputs are empty. That's why you don't see anything happening. What you really want is to call `findTotal()` every time an input changes. When you run `balanceexp()`, you also want to run `findTotal()`. The same goes for `powerexp()` and so on. That's why you should insert `findTotal()` as the final line in each of those functions. They don't require a 0 in every input. Nor does `findTotal()`.

Comment: Well, I added onchange="findTotal()" to the end of every line and its still not working.

Comment: its very possible theres a bug somewhere in my code, its happened to me before when learning from other scripts, Ill rewrite everything by hand from a working script, letter by letter, but when Im done for some reason mine doesnt work. If its easier to write out a new script where two progress bar values total up inside of one more progress bar, I could take that script and make it work for this one. I dont want to take up anyone's time when more than likely its an error on my part. I dont mind rewriting the whole page if it needs it.

Comment: If you follow my instructions, everything will work. I have added a live demonstration to my answer. Click on "Run code snippet" and then on "Full page". All of the code is included.

Comment: Haha! Yours works! and when I tried to edit mine it didnt work, I copied and pasted yours and it works. Thank you so much! Ill spend the rest of the day studying this to see where I went wrong.

Comment: Wonderful! Thanks for accepting my answer. You now have enough reputation points to upvote my answer as well.

Comment: No problem! You stuck it out with me for 2 days, haha. And now it works! You deserve it.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't yet defined balance total.

```
var balancetotal = document.getElementById('balancetotal').value || 0;
var allexp = (balancetotal + powertotal + staminatotal + agilitytotal + controltotal);
```

You will need to do this for all of your fields.

Also, the allExp is a number, not an array, so you do not need to for loop. You can assign it directly to the value of the total input.

You will also want to wait until the DOM is loaded before trying to get values.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() { ... });
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded for more information.